# Highcharts Navigator doesn't change the time

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, navigator

I implemented StockChart in my project. However, when I move the navigator the chart doesn't move as well. As if the movement of the navigator doesn't have any affect on the chart, unlike this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/).

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>


  {% block extra_js %}
    <script>
        $('#id_date_to_3').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
        $('#id_date_from_3').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });


        $(document).ready(function () {

            interval = 20;

            function getData() {
                station_id = $('#id_station_id').val()
                article_description = $('#id_article_description').val()
                date_from = $('#id_date_from_3').val()
                date_to = $('#id_date_to_3').val()
                var chartData = [];
                query_params = '?date_from=' + date_from + '&date_to=' + date_to + "&station_id=" + station_id + "&article_description=" + article_description

                $.getJSON('/pareto/stability-control-data/' + query_params, function (data) {
                    Highcharts.each(data, function (el) {
                        var item = {
                            x: new Date(el[0]),
                            y: Number(el[1]),
                        };
                        console.log(item);
                        chartData.push(item);

                            var chart = new Highcharts.stockChart('chart-container', {
                                xAxis: {
                                    type: 'datetime',
                                    labels: {
                                        format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d}',
                                        rotation: 45,
                                        align: 'left'
                                    },
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                    labels: {
                                        format: '{value} %'
                                    }
                                },
                                rangeSelector: {
                                    selected: 1,
                                },
                                series: [{
                                    name: "Failures",
                                    type: 'spline',
                                    tooltip: {
                                        valueDecimals: 2,
                                        valueSuffix: '%'

                                    },
                                    data: chartData,
                                }],
                                title: {text: 'Failure status %'}
                            });

                    });
                });

            };
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                getData();
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

That's the chart:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq685.png)

and the data: [JSON file](http://myjson.com/1cm44f)

Edit: I have update my answer. I have added more on the JS code and the html headers. I have tried to put the code on JSFiddle but I couldn't make it run. This is the link of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/kashan_91/2a6exny9/11/

I believe there is a problem with the way the data called or something like that. Highcharts code itself is not the cause of the problem but the other JS.

Comment: Hi @Kashan, Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor? I have used your options and they seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/orcem59p/

Comment: @ppotaczek Could you please take a look at my edited question

Comment: I have got a question. Should the data be timestamp instead if String to work? Is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: but still, your code seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6tm9zLr0/